# How to deploy Source Format Git Branch into non-scratch org using jenkins?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, sfdx-plugin

How to deploy Source Format Git Branch meaning SFDX format into non-scratch org or full copy sandbox or production using jenkins?

Comment: You could convert it to metadata format and then deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `sfdx force:source:deploy` command, so if you're using the default path for your source it should be something like:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath force-app --targetusername yourSandboxOrProdUsername
```

You can see more about this command in the [online documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm) or by running `sfdx force:source:deploy -h`.

Comment: Thanks Fabien. We are currently using ant migration (old metadata format) with delta deployment from jenkins deployments . I am wondering if the sfdx can also be done in the same way.

Comment: If you're on the old format, the command is sfdx force:mdapi:deploy, you can use a sourcepath or a package.xml file to specify what you want to deploy.

Answer (score -1):

create a jenkins script in your git repository, in this script you'll execute the SF deploy command.
Create a job in jenkins that runs this script.

hope this helps,

good luck

Comment: Could you provide more details or examples?